# How do you convert a noun into an adjective?

Tags: nouns, adjectives, parts-of-speech, derivational-morphology

What would be the adjectives for nouns like *shopkeeper, country, wife, earring, teacher, father* — and so on and so forth?

Answer (score 2):

Although this might not count an answer directly concerning your question, I think some nouns perform as adjectives when collocating suitably with a second noun. In this case the first noun is called an **attributive noun**. The following is the way my *Merriam-Webster's Collegiate Dictionary [11th edition]* briefly puts it:

> [Some nouns are] often used as an adjective equivalent in attributive
>   position before another noun:
>
> 1 bottle ... *noun, often attrib.*
>
> business ... *noun, often attrib.*
>
> Examples of attributive use of these nouns are *bottle opener* and
>   *business ethics*.

Similarly some attributive collocations of the words you mentioned can be:

**earning**: *earning power/capacity*

**teacher**: *teacher* *appraisal*

With that said, the following is what I could find from concise oxford dictionary [10th edition]. [to my eye most of them seem rare/odd/awkward like *teacherly*]

**father**: fatherly *fatherlike, fatherless.*

**wife**: *wifeless, wifely.*

**teacher**: *teacherly.*

Note, too, that in some instances the conversion of a noun to an adjective may not use the original noun. For example, needing an adjective for "wife", some would choose to use the word *spousal*. Similarly, referring to a teacher, one might use the term *didactic*. If "country" is used to refer to a nation state, the word *national* might be used; but if it "country" is used to mean "non-urban", the adjective *rural* might be used.

The bottom line is, a word doesn't necessarily need to be in adjective form to act as an adjective.

[waiting for natives!]

Comment: English noun compounds (which is what an "attributive use of a noun" means -- one noun modifying another) are very frequent, quite irregular, and usually idiomatic. Consider the meaning difference between _snake bite_ and _pony ride_, for instance; or _door stop, door step, door handle,_ and _door slam_. The error lies in considering that a given word is **really** a noun, but being used as an adjective; instead of saying this word can be used either as an adjective, or as a noun (or as a verb, and often enough). Usage determines category.

Comment: Something to ponder on is the fact that a few nouns may have adjectival forms that differ according to whether they describe its typical characteristics, what it does or what it is associated with. For instance, 'horse' --> 'horselike': "The zebra is a horselike animal of the African grasslands"; 'horse': 'Isn't that one of your horse barns?"; and 'hors(e)y': "Everyone in the family was horsey: they bred horses, they rode horses for pleasure, and they raced horses".

Answer (score 0):

The question is very general so I will provide the general answer. English nouns convert to adjectives in unpredictable ways. Many nouns have convenient adjectives, often with common suffixes like -ly, -ish, -like, or -esque:

- Wife -> Wifely
- Arab -> Arabesque
- Imp -> Impish
- Life -> Lifelike
- Electricity -> Electric

There may be more such suffixes which I am forgetting.

But many nouns do not have easy translations (Country, for instance). There is a class of colloquial adjectivizations (my own colloquialism) which use the suffixes in the first category when they are not technically allowed –

- Shopkeeper -> Shopkeeperly
- Tony Romo (football player) -> Romo-esque

These hybrids are casual but are fun sometimes to inject a little specific flavor to what you are saying, especially if you want to invoke a proper noun.

Many other nouns have strong adjective relatives which either directly map to the noun or need a little context, but have resemblance to the noun itself:

- Country (if you are talking about regions which are not urban) -> Bucolic, Pastoral, Rural
- Country (if you are talking about nations) -> National, Sovereign
- Train -> Locomotive
- Image -> Visual, Illustrative
- Water -> Aquatic, Moist, Damp

The rest, which often are specific "detail words", have no clear one-word adjective pairing and should be used as part of a metaphor or simile:

- Keyboard -> "The stones were arranged in a loose grid, like a keyboard"
- Ox -> "He is an ox"

Comment: Also to add _-ic_ or _-ical_, e.g. angel -> angelic, sphere -> spherical. Or to add _-y_, e.g. fish -> fishy.